# Check user ssh public key in rails 4 app

Tags: mysql, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, ssh-keys

Hi I'm writing simple file uploader app in ruby on rails.
I don't wont a writing registration and login code but but I do not want a stranger to upload files to my server. What I should use to autenticate ?
Can I use SSH public key or mac adress which I wrote in the database, and the server to check if my ssh Public key or mac is in the database ?

Comment: Sorry for my English I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if this is a simple app for just uploading files, rails is kind of overkill on that (you can use Sinatra + CarrierWave for example).

Next thing, result of your work will be an web application... If you want to handle or "filter" users, you have to use standart web authentication mechanism (I can be wrong, I hope maybe can correct me or not):

1. IP filter - you can reject traffic from not-allowed IP ranges, but It's not secure at all, you can fake your IP adress
2. Rack password (look online for Rack::Auth::Basic) - standart mechanism, which broswer handle with list of users and their password, If you decide switch from rails to sinatra no problem, they both work with Rack
3. Or solution you're affraid of - registration mechanism, but dont worry, you can use Devise for Rails or https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication for Sinatra, popular authorization tools :) Ruby ecosystem is quite big, Devise allows you to sending an invitation mail and other cool stuff, check their documentation.. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, or you can use OAuth2 gems to authorize your users by Facebook / Github and other oauth2 supported sites.